# Why did he transfer 4 times the money?

Tags: plot-explanation, gods-crooked-lines

In the Spanish film [God's Crooked Lines](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13229894/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0), we are shown that Alvar has received almost 4 times the fees for Alice's fees.

Castell finds evidence for this and Alvar swears that he has transferred the money to the hospital.

In the end, we learn that Alice has been referring to Dr. Donadío as the Del Olmo who has tasked her with investigating the reason for his son's death. But Dr Donadío and Del Olmo being the same man puts a giant hole in Alice's story of her husband getting her framed. Dr Donadío is the family doctor and the folks in the institution can easily verify his identity.

Based on what we see in the movie Alvar, although has crude techniques, is not involved in fraud that illegally commits Alice to the mental asylum. He even resigns from the post before disclosing the proof he has, Dr Donadío. Had Alvar been up to no good, he would have kept his post, disclosed
Dr Donadío, discredited Alice, and ensured she remained there.

My question - If Alvar and Alice's husband were not working together, why did Alice's husband send Alvar 4 times the money for the treatment (claimed to be a donation)?